# How do I concatenate letters in C

Tags: c

How do I concatenate letters in C?

My code is like this:

For example, at the moment my code is returning 5 letters like this:

```
char validStrings[20][50] = {""};
   for (int j = 0 ; j < 10; ++j){
     for (int k = 0 ; k < count ; ++k){
           char letter = validStrings[k][j];
               if(j == secondCount){
                    secondCount++;
                    putchar('\n');
                }
    }
}
```

What I want is that for every 5 letters ( which is the secondCount value (5) my program concatenates those 5 letters and form a word. I am very new to C so don't know how to achieve it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please saw me full code

Comment: my code is just an example I just need to know how to concatenate words within a for loop. It can be any  other example

Comment: Just follow the curriculum of a basic C course. That's a more effective way of learning.

Comment: I don't have the time atm, I just need to know how to thats all

Comment: "my code is returning 5 letters like this" Please make a [mre] of that, show the output and manually make up the output you want instead.

Comment: The answer to all "no idea how to start" questions is: "read, find working examples, try, fix, redo". I.e. read some text book or tutorial, find a HelloWorld or sample code, try to change it in small steps towards your goal, test, debug; then try the next iteration. Once you got something and it does not work for the very small change you made away from something working, then it is time to ask a focused question here, according to [ask] and maybe using the compromise described here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: Be warned. Sometimes questions asking for "I just want to know how to do this specific thing. I do not have time to learn the basics." will receive answers which I call "homework traps". They consist of code solutions which strictly speaking do solve the assignment, but are so obviously not what you or any fellow student could have come up with, that any teacher realises that the code is not written and even less understood by you. So with the question as it is currently asked, be very careful if you actually get an answer. If you cannot explain it do not use it.

Comment: thanks @Yunnosch I really appreciate your input and also agree. If I am not able to explain something if I am honest I am not using it anyway :D